# How to get element text in an anchor using lxml and requests?

Tags: python, tree, python-requests, lxml

I'm studying python requests and now I need to know how to parse a `html` using `xpath`.

I got the `xpath` from Antica on https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds

That's my code right now.

```
r = requests.get(U'https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds')
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
worlds = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a/text()')
print(worlds)
```

I tried to get the text`"Antica"` back, but the `xpath` function returns to me an empty list.

Comment: look into beautiful soup for web page parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using beautiful soup because it's a lot easier.

Anyway if you still wish to do it with lxml, you could try something like

```
r = requests.get(U'https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds')
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
all_worlds = tree.xpath('/html/body//tr/td/a/@href')
for url in all_worlds:
    print(url)
```

Comment: Amazing, I changed the @href to /title() and got the titles to wich world. 
I'll check out beautiful soap, thanks.